# Filling multiple td for one th

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I need to make a table with answers to a question. I am putting questions in th and I need multiple answers related to that question.

[image]

The main problem is that I can not achieve that answers follow count(number and percents).  I made 
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/drobke/pen/NyEwGK) so that you can see what I get there. I will be filling this tables with JSON on Angular2 with *ngFor.

[image]

```
<div class="table-wrapper" id='table'>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Whats your gender?</th>
    <th>What's your age?</th>
    <th>How often do you train?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  
      <span>Female</span>
      <span>Male</span>
    </td>
    <td class='flex'>
      <span>15-24</span>
      <span>25-34</span>
    </td>
    <td>      
      <span>Less than one a month</span>
      <span>A few times a month</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        573
      </span>
      <span>
        299
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>20%</span>
      <span>68%</span>
    </td>
    <td>     
      <span>5%</span>
      <span>3%</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        66%
      </span>
      <span>
        34%
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>      
      <span>173</span>
      <span>391</span>
    </td>
    <td>      
      <span>173</span>
      <span>391</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

css

```
.table-wrapper {
  width: 850px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
span {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

td, th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width; 40px;
}
td {
  max-height: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp)?

Comment: No, but now i saw examples and it's working. Thanks

Comment: Go ahead and accept one of the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `colspan` on the first line of your `table` and also make your second line with `th` instead of `td` since it's a second line of `header`.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width: 850px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
span {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

td, th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width; 40px;
}
td {
  max-height: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  height: 2px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal{  
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track:horizontal { 
  background: #fff;
  height: 2px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper" id='table'>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Whats your gender?</th>
    <th colspan="2">What's your age?</th>
    <th colspan="2">How often do you train?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>  
      <span>Female</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span>Male</span>
    </th>
    <th class='flex'>
      <span>15-24</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span>25-34</span>
    </th>
    <th>      
      <span>Less than one a month</span>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span>A few times a month</span>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        573
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
        299
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>20%</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>68%</span>
    </td>
    <td>     
      <span>5%</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>3%</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
        66%
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>
        34%
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>      
      <span>173</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>391</span>
    </td>
    <td>      
      <span>173</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>391</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

here i am sharing the link of JSFIDDLE

i edited your code, i think it is useful to you

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Whats your gender?</th>
    <th  colspan=2>What's your age?</th>
    <th  colspan=2>How often do you train?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>

      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Male</td>    
      <td>15-24</td>
      <td>25-34</td>   
      <td>Less than one a month</td>
      <td>A few times a month</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

      <td>
        573
      </td>
      <td>
        299
      </td>


      <td>20%</td>
      <td>68%</td>


      <td>5%</td>
      <td>3%</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>

      <td>
        66%
      </td>
      <td>
        34%
      </td>


      <td>173</td>
      <td>391</td>

      <td>173</td>
      <td>391</td>

  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

in css

```
 .table-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
th
{
  text-align:center;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
span {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

td, th {

    padding: 8px;
    width; 40px;
}
td {
  max-height: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9su2je6/6/

Comment: Please expolain what you did editing answer, avoid code only answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: here use colspan="2" for th it allows two td's and make width od the table is 100% it is useful to responsive purpose

Answer (score 2):

You can use the colspan attribute on the th tags:

```
<div class="table-wrapper" id='table'><table>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2">Whats your gender?</th>
  <th colspan="2">What's your age?</th>
  <th colspan="2">How often do you train?</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span>Female</span></td>
  <td><span>Male</span></td>
  <td><span>15-24</span></td>
  <td><span>25-34</span></td>
  <td><span>Less than one a month</span></td>
  <td><span>A few times a month</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span>573</span></td>
  <td><span>299</span></td>
  <td><span>20%</span></td>
  <td><span>68%</span></td>
  <td><span>5%</span></td>
  <td><span>3%</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><span>66%</span></td>
  <td><span>34%</span></td>
  <td><span>173</span></td>
  <td><span>391</span></td>
  <td><span>173</span></td>
  <td><span>391</span></td>
</tr>
```